# My query returns an Id instead instead of the actual values

Tags: django, django-models

I have the query below on the following tables but my output returns the product Id instead of the product name. Any suggestion or help would be highly appreciated.

```
#my query
Stock.objects.values('name').annotate(List=Count('name'), total=Sum('quantity'))

#model.py
class Product (models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
     

 class Stock (models.Model):
      name = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      quantity = models.IntegerField(defualt=0)
      ........
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `values` it gives you a dictionary of values and any `ForeignKey` is represented as their ids (because they are stored that way in the column).

Since you want information for `Product` instances you should instead make a query on `Product` and annotate the information you want on this queryset:

```py
from django.db.models import Count, Sum


products = Product.objects.annotate(List=Count('stock'), total=Sum('stock__quantity'))

for product in products:
    print(product.name, product.List, product.total)
```