# The field returns null even though it contains a value

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-templates

When creating a new object (music track), I specify the name of the playlist in one of the fields. However, after saving the data from the form, the value of the playlist field in the frontend is null, although there is a value in this field in the admin panel. I do not understand how I can get the text value of a field name (playlist) that I specify when creating, it is always equivalent null in the frontend.

models.py:

```
class Composition(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    playlist = models.ForeignKey('PlayList', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    time_length = models.DecimalField(blank=True, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    audio_file = models.FileField(validators=[validate_is_audio])
    cover_image = models.ImageField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.time_length:
            audio_length = get_audio_length(self.audio_file)
            self.time_length = audio_length
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class PlayList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

my views

```
def homepage(request):
    composition = Composition.objects.all()
    composition_list = list(Composition.objects.all().values())
    return render(request, 'base.html', {
        'composition': composition,
        'composition_list': composition_list
    })

def addSong(request):
    form = AddCompositionForm()
    if request.POST:
        form = AddCompositionForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            playlist = form.cleaned_data.get('playlist')
            music_playlist = PlayList.objects.get_or_create(name=playlist)
            instance.playlist = music_playlist[0]
            instance.save()
            return redirect("music_player:home_page")

    return render(request, 'addSong.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

frontend function (in the end of my base.html):

```
<div class="music-list">
    <div class="playlist-information">
        <div class="small-img-box">
            <img src="{% static 'main/media/music_placeholder.png' %}" alt="small-img-box">
        </div>
        <div class="small-playlist-info">
            <p class="playlistname">Title</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{{ composition_list | json_script:"musics" }}

<script>

    const player = document.querySelector('.audio-player')
    const play = document.querySelector('.play-track')
    const prev = document.querySelector('.prev-track')
    const next = document.querySelector('.next-track')
    const duration = document.querySelector('.total_duration')
    const currentTime = document.querySelector('.current-time')
    const progress = document.querySelector('.slider')
    const progress_container = document.querySelector('.bar')
    const play_button = document.querySelector('.play_btn')
    const progress_line = document.querySelector('.fill')

    const audio_tracks = document.querySelector('.songs')
    const song_title = document.querySelector('.songname')
    const artist = document.querySelector('.songauthor')
    const playlist_name = document.querySelector('.playlistname')
    const music_img = document.querySelector('.music_cover')

    const add_song = document.querySelector('.add_song')

    // init music indexing
    let compositionIndex = 0

    // get music from DOM
    const musics = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('musics').textContent)

    // functions
    const setSRC = () => {
        player.src = `{{ MEDIA_URL }}/${musics[compositionIndex].audio_file}`
        song_title.textContent = musics[compositionIndex].title
        artist.textContent = musics[compositionIndex].artist
        music_img.setAttribute('src', `{{ MEDIA_URL }}/${musics[compositionIndex].cover_image}`)
        playlist_name.textContent = musics[compositionIndex].playlist
    }

    setSRC()

</script>

</body>
 
</html>
```

value in admin panel:

[image: admin_panel]

value in javascript:

[image]

All fields except the playlist are not equal to null and work correctly.

P.S. In the django console the playlist field is displayed correctly:

[image]

Comment: It would be displaying in the Django console after you added the `__str__` method, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, now everything is displayed normally in the django console after adding this method. But my frontend function still says that the value of the playlist field is undefined and is null. I don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: Please see [ask] and read up on creating a [mre]. How do you suppose we would know what `musics` is? Where does it come from? Since your problem is with the frontend why are you not showing the relevant frontend code and instead showing your models and views?

Comment: Sorry. I tried to add all the missing lines of code. I hope this helps solve my problem.

Comment: `.values()` doesn't return foreign keys directly, you'll instead get a field `playlist_id` (the field with a `_id` suffix). See the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values): "_If you have a field called foo that is a ForeignKey, the default values() call will return a dictionary key called foo_id, since this is the name of the hidden model attribute that stores the actual value (the foo attribute refers to the related model)._"

Comment: Does this answer your question: [My query returns an Id instead instead of the actual values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67100471/my-query-returns-an-id-instead-instead-of-the-actual-values)

Comment: Thank you, i changed `values()` to `composition_list = list(Composition.objects.all().values('title', 'artist', 'playlist__name', 'time_length', 'audio_file', 'cover_image'))` and changed the name of the `playlist` field in the front-end function to `playlist__name` and everything worked!

Answer (score 1):

You should return `name` of playlist in `PlayList` model itself using [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method so:

```py
class PlayList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"
```

Comment: I added these lines and makemigrations, but it didn’t change anything, anyway, the value of the playlist field on my frontend is undefined.